# How do I display an image when I click a button (Like MessageBox.Show)?

Tags: c#, image

How do I display an image when I click a button ? Like MessageBox.Show, it will open a new window. Unfortunately MessageBox only do it on text. how about images ?

Comment: Open a new form? Your question is too broad, [ask]

Comment: have you tried making a form with an image on, and open it like a dialog box

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion how about if you:

- Create a new windows form instead with `PictureBox` inside.
- Load the image on the `PictureBox` before showing it
- Use `Form.ShowDialog(this)`
- Return `DialogResult` upon clicking the buttons you define in your windows form

Comment: How I create a new windows form ? I am new to C#

Comment: Here's a tutorial from MSDN that might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx

Answer (score 0):

we can create image (or) pic to be clickable links by using this code
`<a href="http://www.w3.org"><img src="w3c_home.gif"
  alt="World Wide Web Consortium Home"
  width="72"height="46"border="0"/></a>`see in this blog
http://www.facebookliteapp.com/2015/06/facebook-lite-for-Android-pc-laptops.html